# creating a game clock with custom time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, clock

I'm trying to make a `GameClock` like a real clock, but with a custom time.
The clock is running but it is delaying and I can't find the problem. Thanks for help.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    while (true) {
        Sec = DateTime.Now.Second;
        if (Hour == 23 && Min == 59 && Sec == 0){
            Hour = 0;
            Min = 0;
        } else if (Min == 59 && Sec == 0){
            Min = 0;
            Hour += 1;
        } else if (Sec == 0) {
            Min += 1;
        } 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "delaying"? Does it delay your program in some way? How do yo call this code?

Comment: What do I mean by delay , it is that the hours are delayed by 1 second per minutor 1 minute per hour and 24 minutes a day.

Comment: You do know you have some delay because of the asynchronous nature of a timer, right?

Comment: I know there's no way to make 100% accurate, but must try to improve the delay because 24 minutes per day is very high.

Comment: Could you mention how the values of `Hour` or `Min` are being assigned?

Comment: is a simple int variable  public int Min = 0;
 public int Hour = 0;

Answer (score 2):

i think it should be like

```
while (true) {
    Sec = DateTime.Now.Second;
    if (Hour == 23 && Min == 59 && Sec == 59){
        Hour = 0;
        Min = 0;
    } else if (Min == 59 && Sec == 59){
        Min = 0;
        Hour += 1;
    } else if (Sec == 59) {
        Min += 1;
    } 
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you *show* changes (mark them): either in words or as comments in code. Some explanation of why OP code doesn't work (what was wrong) would be nice too.

Comment: I 've used the code this way before , using 59 seconds. but the delay is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you are doing all this work when you can just print out easily:

```
    Debug.Log(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
    Debug.Log(System.DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString());
    Debug.Log(System.DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString());
    Debug.Log(System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
```

Comment: Oooh that sounds like a school assignment :).